# Entity Framework related Error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()     at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)     at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)     at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.b__35()     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()     at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()     at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: So.... have you tried searching for: `The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding`?

Comment: I think you need to show some code to see how and why this is happening.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention is: I am getting this error every day around a specified time only.

Comment: Is there by any chance a backup process, or index rebuild running during that time?

Comment: I am sure that there is no backup process is being running during that time. But how can i know about Index Rebuild process?

Comment: It would be a task, scheduled like a backup task

Comment: The time can happen if the timeout is explicitly set to a low value or when a deadlock occurs or something is forcing a single connection. Since it's on a save action, and only during a specific time, it's most likely some maintenance is going on.

Comment: Although there is no explicit Task has been scheduled for Index Rebuilding as well not on Windows task Scheduler. Is there any inbuilt SQL Service which does it implicity?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.... I would love it because it though ;-)    ... what kind of environment are you running this? (full)sql-server, windows server? Azure? Virtual hosts? I think it's more due to the infrastructure/maintenance than that it is EF related.

Comment: Its a Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server Web Edition hosted on AWS Cloud.

Comment: I have just started SQL Server Profiler so that it will catch all the ongoing events. Hopefully using this i will be able to know the exact cause.

Comment: Will get back to you with the updates. Thanks alot for your time and as well as the information too. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: Thanks! ... let me know.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Hope you are doing great !!! There was no Deadlock occurred as i have checked the SQL Profiler as well.

Comment: This is SQL Profiler Trace for the same record when it is updating successfully at 10:18 PM:: RPC:Completed exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET [LASTMODIFIEDON] = @0
WHERE ([ID] = @1)
',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 decimal(10,0)',@0='2018-06-04 22:18:44.0925691',@1=1414 EntityFramework  User_For_SQL_Server_DB 0 2 0 0 18452 64 2018-06-04 22:18:44.090 2018-06-04 22:18:44.090

Comment: This is SQL Profiler Trace for the same record when it is failing to update at 02:32 AM:: RPC:Completed exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET [LASTMODIFIEDON] = @0
WHERE ([ID] = @1)
',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 decimal(10,0)',@0='2018-06-05 02:32:02.6991780',@1=1414 EntityFramework  User_For_SQL_Server_DB 0 2 0 30000 1516 64 2018-06-05 02:32:02.700 2018-06-05 02:32:32.700

Comment: When its failing it is showing 30000 as a duration which means waiting for 30 seconds afterwards it failed where as in successful case it is showing 0 as a duration.

Comment: For the unsuccessful run; what are the nearby previous entries?

Comment: SQL Operation for Insert and Update for other Tables.

Comment: Hmm, I hoped there was something which would provide some info about the timeout, a long running operation or something. I am affraid this is out of my league :-/

Comment: Once again, Thanks alot.

Comment: Funny thing; happening here (seriously). Similar case: 2 servers, 1 mssql, other web/IIS. errors; "underlying connection has been closed" and "The timeout period elapsed...". Cause; nightly maintenance of the infrastructure provider.

Comment: Who is the Infrastructure Provider in this case?

Comment: It's a local small hosting provider.

Comment: But i don;t think AWS is doing anything like this.